# Haskell function to get process pid by port number

Tags: haskell, networking, process, signals, port

I have a *warp* server running locally on a known port. I would like to send termination signal to this application programmatically using haskell. If I knew the application pid, I could use **signalProcess** function from *System.Posix.Signals* module. Unfortunately all my attempts to find the right package with required functionality didn't bring any result.

As an alternative approach to send a signal to an application, I could use haskell wrapper around shell and try to kill the server by the port number. But this solution to me looks a bit ugly and I would rather use some build-in haskell library to do this.

Comment: is the question how to get the `ProcessID` of your server? What about [`getProcessID`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.0/docs/System-Posix-Process-ByteString.html#v:getProcessID)?

Comment: to be honest this looks like something you should do with your OS tools

Comment: couldn't you use [System.Exit `exitSuccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/System-Exit.html) instead of terminating the application from outside

Comment: My usual approach to this problem is to provide a `stop` endpoint in the server that's accessible only on an administration interface, e.g. localhost. This makes your application much easier to manage, including when you want to run tests